# Selenium doesn't recognize element by XPath

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome, xpath

i am sorry to create a topic about this, but this little thing has been boggling my brain for the past 2 hours. Chrome returns the right element by Xpath as well as by javascript script, but Selenium tells me that in the very code, *that Chrome runs perfectly fine* is an error:

> javascript error: missing ) after argument list

This is the code I am currently trying:

```
    driver.execute_script('let clickable = document.evaluate("//a[contains(@onclick,\"openFbLWin\")]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; clickable.click();')
```

i know its a bit messy, but overall the most important thing is *//a[contains(@onclick,\"openFbLWin\")]* 
as for the XPath selector.

Comment: Could you plesae give us a [minimal reproducible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also, what website are you scraping?

Comment: Hello,
Currently scraping AddMeFast.com, which is click4click scheme website.

What kind-of answer are you expecting? Selenium can't find elements by given XPath or execute javascript propertly

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because when you run this in python, it converts `"//a[contains(@onclick,\"openFbLWin\")]"` into `"//a[contains(@onclick,"openFbLWin")]"`, without the slashes. Then, when this is run in `javascript`, it can't parse the string because there is a double-quote inside of another double-quote. To fix this, change your xPath to `"//a[contains(@onclick,'openFbLWin')]"`.

You should use `selenium`'s inbuilt search and click tools, though. It is much more readable and faster (use [find_element_by_xpath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) and [click](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html))

Comment: Hello, 
I've tried doing this using their built-in functions (find_element_by_xpath), but it did not find any elements either. I will try to take a deeper look into the slashes. This is actually the first time Im using Python for something bigger :D 
I tried 
core_like = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,'openFbLWin')]")
but selenium isn't returning any elements. (If i try to search for the XPath in chrome, it works)